# Problems to downgrade scipy to 1.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pip

I have scipy 1.6.1 installed and i need to downgrade it to 1.1.0, but that's the error i'm getting.

`Python` version i'm using is `3.9.0`

`Pip` version is `21.0.1`

```
PS E:\Mestrado\projetos> py -m pip install scipy==1.1.0
Collecting scipy==1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'E:\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ytijut7e'
       cwd: C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\
  Complete output (140 lines):
  C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py:114: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries openblas not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  Could not locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  Could not locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
  customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  flame_info:
    libraries flame not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Python\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Python\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 474, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 388, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage   
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage    
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage   
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage    
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 19, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'E:\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904
  Complete output (11 lines):
  C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py:114: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.6.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.6.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.6.1
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'E:\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-iazwnxsd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'E:\Python\Include\scipy'
         cwd: C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\
    Complete output (149 lines):
    C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py:114: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see 
the module's documentation for alternative uses
      import imp

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils       
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']        
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in E:\Python\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['E:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\', 'E:\\Python\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 474, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-805z0ik4\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\setup.py", line 388, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage 
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage  
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1018, in add_subpackage 
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 984, in get_subpackage  
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 926, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 19, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to e:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy-1.6.1.dist-info\
   from E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\~cipy-1.6.1.dist-info
  Moving to e:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\
   from E:\Python\Lib\site-packages\~cipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'E:\Python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Tarfine Falqueto\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-805z0ik4\\scipy_2bfefe1ea8a24dc09210a322e3f47904\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Tarfine Falqueto\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-iazwnxsd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'E:\Python\Include\scipy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scipy project prepares binary-wheels to make installing easier for the end-users as *compilation from sources* is a huge pain (C, C++, Fortran, BLAS/LAPACK and more complications).

Installing *from sources* is very hard (especially on windows) and **is actually needed if there are no binaries available**! It's really hard...

In your case, you are out of luck. scipy `1.1.0` was released when python `3.9` was not around and therefore [the only binary-wheels available for `1.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.1.0/#files) are:

- Python 2.7
- Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6

Only using one of those Python versions you would get binary-wheels when selecting `scipy 1.1.0`. Otherwise, the installer tries to *compile from sources* (which won't do without a lot of preparation).

So do one of the following:

- A: *relax* your selection/preference of scipy-version
- B: *relax* your selection/preference of python-version
- C: go for linux and install from sources
- D: not recommended: prepare your windows to be able to install from sources

Comment: Thanks @sascha. I ended up moving on with B. As I can't to linux atm, i installed a separate Python 3.6.5 instance and downloaded `scipy 1.1.0`. It worked smoothly.